# Removing a single key value of UserDefaults in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am tracking a user's preferences in my iOS app using `UserDefaults` -- when a user selects a table cell, it adds the cell's text to my key. That part works.

Now, I want to allow the user to remove the matching key value from the key when a row is selected. If a cell says "Episode 1", it should remove the value from `UserDefaults`.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1411182-removeobject), there's an instance method for `removeObject`. Here's what I wrote:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
    if let datastring = TableData[indexPath.row] as? String {
        if !myarray.contains(datastring) {
            myarray.append(datastring)
            defaults.removeObject(myarray, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
```

This returns an error for `Extra argument in call` -- I assume it means `myarray`, but if I can't add that argument, how can I tell it to remove only one value (stored in `myarray`)?

If I print the `UserDefaults.standard`, it will return a list of stored episode values like `["First Episode", "Second Episode", "Third Episode"]

Any idea how I can remove `Third Episode` when that cell is clicked here?

Comment: [removeObject()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1411182-removeobject) has only one argument, the key.

Comment: Just use  defaults.removeObject(forKey: "SavedStringArray")

Comment: @iMHitesh: Trying that now but it doesn't seem to remove anything now.

Comment: That's correct -- included in the code above. As a note, I am using `UserDefaults` because this is Swift 3.

Comment: @darkginger : As per your first statement - you are adding value in defaults on selecting a row. As per your second statement - you are removing the value from defaults when row is selected. I am a bit confused.

Comment: You don't need to call `synchronize`. You need to save the updated array in userdefaults, it will overwrite the previous value. You don't need to remove anything from userdefaults

Comment: @Vinaykrishnan No, `.synchronize()` is not necessary anymore (and this has been the case for years). Nowadays, it's even the opposite: calling it can create lags and issues. Don't use it. Don't tell people to use it. It will soon be officially deprecated anyway.

Comment: @Moritz, thanks sure will keep in mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have following code which will work for you.

```
if myarray.contains(datastring) {
    myarray.remove(at: myarray.index(of: datastring)!)
} else {
    myarray.append(datastring)
}
defaults.set(myarray, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
```

This code will remove element from array and set array again in User defaults for same key, So it will replace you array with new array.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @darkginger, Pleasure mine. Happy to Help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add if string is not present or remove the string if it is present. And then update the array.
Then set that array for the key.

```
if !myarray.contains(datastring) {
    myarray.append(datastring)
} else {
    myarray = myarray.filter{$0 != datastring}
}
defaults.set(myarray, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
```

Comment: Trying it now but Xcode flags: `Value of type '[String]' has no member 'removeObject'` for the `myarray.removeObject(datastring)` line

Comment: There is no need to call synchronize

Answer (score 0):

You can try This logic for array of type String i.e. [String]

```
    var arrStr:[String] = ["Cat","Rat","Mouse"]
    print(arrStr)

    let datastring = "Rat"
    if !arrStr.contains(datastring) {
        arrStr.append(datastring)
    } else {
        arrStr.remove(at: arrStr.index(of: datastring)!)
    }

    print(arrStr)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(arrStr, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```